# PHP form redirects before checking input

Tags: php, forms, redirect

The form I'm using for this example is recycled one I've been using for a while, since I don't have knowledge or time to learn PHP. It works, but not exactly like I would like it. For instance, when someone enters name and email in the form and submits, its supposed to redirect the user to freepage.html. However, it "blinks" the actual "freepage.php" with the info that has been input. Usually that lasts 1-2 seconds, and then the redirect begins.

The other problem I have is if a user doesnt enter the info, "All fields are mandatory" warning displays on that freepage.php, only this time that page doesny "blink" on the screen for a second, it stays there with the warning displayed and the only way to fix it is to click the "back" button in the browser.

Can somebody point me how could I make this form bit better....

this is how the php file looks like

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">google.load("jqueryui", "1.5.2");</script>
            <? 
        if($_POST['name']!="" and $_POST['email']!=""){


    $headers    = "From: Sender";
    $message    = 
            strtoupper($_POST['name'])."
            ".strtoupper($_POST['email'])."
            ";
    echo str_replace("\n","<br />", $message);
    $headers2   = "From: Sender <info@gmail.com>\nContent-Type: text/plain;                               charset=UTF-8; format=flowed\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\nX-Mailer: PHP\n";
    $message2   = "
    Hello ".($_POST['name'])."  

            ";

    mail("$_POST[email]", "Thanks for entering", $message2, $headers2);


    $myFile = "info-file.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
    $stringData =            "$_POST[name]*$_POST[email]*".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."*".date("d-m-Y H:i")."
             ";
    fwrite($fh, $stringData);
    fclose($fh);


    ?>

    echo '<script>document.location="freepage.html"; </script>';

    <?
} else {
    echo "All fields are mandatory";
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("All fields are mandatory");
    </script>
    <?
}
    ?>
```

form looks like this

```
        <form method="post" action="freepage.php" name="popups" id="popups">
        <fieldset>
        <label for=name accesskey=U ><span class="required">*</span> Name</label>
        <br />
        <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="" /> 
        <br />
        <label for=email accesskey=E ><span class="required">*</span> Email</label>
        <br />
        <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="button" />
        </fieldset>  
        <br />
        </form>
```

Comment: "since I don't have knowledge or time to learn PHP" so hire someone.

Comment: thanks @Dagon appreciate the help, very smart answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it "blink" is because you must wait that the server send the mail before the redirection.

For the warning : "All fields are mandatory".

- If the form is on the same page (freepage.php) the form will work
  event if it's displayed.
- If the form isn't on the same page just add a redirection (html link
  or javascript location) or insert the form after the php code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Sorry for the confusing names, but the page users will be redirected too is "freepage.html", freepage.php is just the code for the form to work. I understand the "blink" part, but is there a way to display the mandatory fields warning before the redirection starts?

Comment: Usually the php code is on the same page than the form, so with an "echo" the warning is at the top of the screen and there's no need to redirect.
In your code there's a javascript alert, so just add a redirection after the alert and when the user will click on "ok" he will be redirected.
else {
    echo "All fields are mandatory";
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("All fields are mandatory");
    window.location='target.htmlOrPhp';
    </script>
    <?
}

Answer (score 0):

use empty function in for loop to check the fields are empty or not then in form action use php
self then if the checking part is done the inside if use header to redirect to other page